# How to unlocalize an item under SDL Tridion using web client interface

Tags: tridion

I made a mistake localizing a page template under SDL Tridion and I want to unlocalize it but when I right click it the option "unlocalize" is not available. How can I do that? Is there another way to unlocalize items?
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Removed localization and sdl tags which are unrelated to this question (sdl does not map to the company SDL or product SDL Tridion)

Comment: Nice question, could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To localize or unlocalize an item, you must have Localize permissions for the Folder or Structure Group in which the item is stored. Also please note it can only be done in the Publication where the item is actually localized.

So if you do not see the option to unlocalize I would have your permissions checked, or you are in a parent or child Publication. The option should be available in your context (right click) menu under the BluePrinting sub menu, or you can select the item (single click which highlights it) and go to the Organize tab in the ribbon toolbar.

Comment: I had not permissions. Thanks a lot for the suggestion.